# chromedrive.exe has stopped working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Am running the automation suite on the below configuration

Selenium: 3.11.0
Chrome: 65.0.3325.181
Chromedriver: 2.37
JDK: 1.8
OS: Windows 7 Enterprise(64 -bit)

On mid of the execution am getting an error as Chromedriver.exe has stopped working and the execution got stopped.

To resolve this, have tried with different version of selenium and chromedriver. Couldn't able to resolve the issue.

**Issue Image**

[image: **Issue Image**]

**ChromeDriver Log:** [Log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EhtB9ei9PZ1AzIWzBIJRSpzrnEfbSd9u/view?usp=sharing)

**Update:**

Am getting this error whenever my code triggers the `driver.get(URL)` or `driver.navigate().to(URL)` command. FYI, am not sure this gonna help or not. Just to give more insight, my code will access two sites, in that one is https and another one is http. Am getting the exception whenever it access the http site.

Comment: It might be the URL that you are hitting. can you type the url in the browser and then the application launches, copy the url from the address bar and use it in your code.

Comment: It could be due to a lack of memory. Since your log file is over 30mb, try to run your script with a higher log level to reduce/disable it. You could also try to relaunch the browser if the script is too long.

Comment: @FlorentB.Even disable the log. am getting the same error.

Comment: @Bendram: Its happening randomly in the suite. If I ran the same script again it executes well. Don't think its due to the URL.

Comment: Is the error happening at any particular line? Update the question with the relevant code block, HTML and error trace logs.

Comment: @DebanjanB: As said earlier, its not happening on any specific piece of code block or line. It's happening randomly in the suite.

Comment: @Manigandan did you found the issue?